# Supertest attaching file: Unsupported Media Type: multipart/form-data;

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs, supertest

Trying to send file via attach method is not working..

```
await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post('/uploads/avatar')
        .set('Content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
        .auth(userToken.accessToken, { type: 'bearer' })
        .attach('file', buffer, 'test.jpg')
        .expect(({ status, body }) => {
          console.log(body);
          expect(status).toBe(400);
        });
```

Have tried without set content type, passing options on attach method and i'm gettin same error always. Look the docs on superagent and the tried like it says, but nothing to.

tried pass blob, buffer and filePath... And always the same

This is the console.log of all request

```
_events: [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] {
          listener: [Function: bound _clearTimeout]
        }
      },
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _agent: false,
      _formData: FormData {
        _overheadLength: 150,
        _valueLength: 37351,
        _valuesToMeasure: [],
        writable: false,
        readable: true,
        dataSize: 0,
        maxDataSize: 2097152,
        pauseStreams: true,
        _released: false,
        _streams: [
          '----------------------------705062276704130245747665\r\n' +
            'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n' +
            '\r\n',
          <Buffer 75 ab 5a 8a 66 a0 7b f8 e9 7a 06 da b1 ee b8 ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 01 00 60 00 60 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 06 04 05 06 05 04 06 06 05 06 ... 37301 more bytes>,
          [Function: bound ]
        ],
        _currentStream: null,
        _insideLoop: false,
        _pendingNext: false,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function] },
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _boundary: '--------------------------705062276704130245747665'
      },
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:41895/uploads/avatar',
      _header: {
        'user-agent': 'node-superagent/3.8.3',
        authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InVzZXJAY29sbGFtYXAub3JnIiwiZmlyc3RuYW1lIjoiVXNlciIsImxhc3RuYW1lIjoiVXNlciIsImF2YXRhciI6IiIsImlhdCI6MTYxNDEwMjk2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjE0MTAzMjY5fQ.YRud3pAACN51HDRleuc1lYd4-yuyrlANY9kmwSpA1O0'
      },
      header: {
        'User-Agent': 'node-superagent/3.8.3',
        Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6InVzZXJAY29sbGFtYXAub3JnIiwiZmlyc3RuYW1lIjoiVXNlciIsImxhc3RuYW1lIjoiVXNlciIsImF2YXRhciI6IiIsImlhdCI6MTYxNDEwMjk2OSwiZXhwIjoxNjE0MTAzMjY5fQ.YRud3pAACN51HDRleuc1lYd4-yuyrlANY9kmwSpA1O0'
      },
      writable: true,
      _redirects: 0,
      _maxRedirects: 0,
      cookies: '',
      qs: {},
      _query: [],
      qsRaw: [],
      _redirectList: [],
      _streamRequest: false,
      _buffer: true,
      app: Server {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          request: [Function: bound lookup],
          connection: [Function: connectionListener],
          clientError: [Function: bound defaultClientErrorHandler]
        },
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 0,
        _handle: TCP {
          reading: false,
          onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
          [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
        },
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 0,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::0',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 916
      },
      _asserts: [],
      _server: Server {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          request: [Function: bound lookup],
          connection: [Function: connectionListener],
          clientError: [Function: bound defaultClientErrorHandler]
        },
        _eventsCount: 3,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 0,
        _handle: TCP {
          reading: false,
          onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
          [Symbol(owner)]: [Circular]
        },
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 0,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 40000,
        _connectionKey: '6::::0',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 916
      }
    }
```

My controller :

```
@Post('avatar')
  async uploadFile(
    @Req() req: FastifyRequest,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    @Res() reply: FastifyReply<any>,
    @GetUser() user: UserEntity,
  ): Promise<string> {
    try {
      if (!req.isMultipart) {
        reply.send(new BadRequestException());
        return;
      }

      const data = await req.file();
      const buffer = await data.toBuffer();

      const { isSuccess, message } = await this.uploadsService.uploadAvatar(
        buffer,
        user,
      );

      if (isSuccess) {
        reply
          .code(200)
          .header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
          .send({ statusCode: 200, body: {} });
      } else {
        reply
          .code(422)
          .header('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
          .send({
            statusCode: 422,
            body: {
              status: 'fail',
              errors: message,
            },
          });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      throw errorHandler.handle(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the target controller ?

Comment: Done bro!!! Now have the controller code

Comment: It's very strange... because on postman it's working just fine

Comment: Supertest and Fastify sometimes have trouble talking with each other properly. What if you use fastfy's `inject` testing methods?

Comment: Your Content-type is not in correct case, have you tried change that?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to attach files using supertest, you have to use another construction when declaring your fields from form.

Here is a working example:

```
it('Check post with correct data', function(done) {
    api.post(_url)
        .set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+tokn)
        .field('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
        .field('name', 'asdadas')
        .attach('icon', 'test.png')
        .expect(201)
        .expect('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            .end(function(err, res) {
               expect(res.body).to.have.property("category_id");
               expect(res.body.category_id).to.equal(2);
               done();
           });
    });
```

My code is old, but there is no problem in using with async/await and arrow functions. Here is just an idea.

Comment: Wich version of supertest are u using... got the same error here

Comment: at the time i wrote this test, supertest is pinned in my package.json in version `1.2.0 `. Sorry. @Damasceno

Comment: Thanks anyway bro :D